# WSO2 Identity Server web console not responding

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I installed WSO2 Identity Server on Ubuntu 14, and I could log in to the web console and dashboard. I recently changed some settings with regards to the system not referring back to 'localhost' so that we could access the system remotely. This all seemed to be working ok.

But now I cannot access the console or dashboard any more. I have checked that the WSO2 service is running, but the web console does not display, it just times out.

The question I have is, how can I troubleshoot this issue? As I don't really want to have to re-install from scratch when I have already done so much configuring!

Any help on this would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask?

Comment: What are the changes you done in WSO2 IS configuration in [IS_home]/reprository/conf or else? Plus what is the version of WSO2 IS and java your using?

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding. The Java version is 'java version "1.7.0_80"'

Comment: WSO2 IS version: 5.0

Comment: with regards to the changes I made, they were mainly in the .xml files that were pointing to localhost:9443 which were preventing the redirection.

Comment: Can you add an error displayed in console ?